# Hedera Meta/Gasless Transaction

Tags: hedera-hashgraph

I am working on gasless/meta transactions.
Is it possible in hedera to sign the transaction using one account and submit/execute and also pay for the transaction by a different account?

Answer (score 2):

By gasless I'm assuming you mean in the context of smart contracts in which case the answer is no for now. The payer for the transaction is the `msg.sender` as seen by the contract.

However, native services such as the token service support a model where Alice pays for a transaction that involved Bob sending tokens (or hbar) to Carol.

Alice has to sign the transaction to approve the tx fee payment, Bob also has to sign to approve the transfer or tokens/hbar.